# How to convert string from pandas dataframe to 3-dimensional array in numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I've exported a pandas data frame containing a numpy array of shape (75, 100, 3) to csv. When I import this csv file to get my dataframe, my numpy array is a string. I'm having so much problem trying to convert this string to numpy array of shape (75, 100, 3).

My string is like:

```py
[[[198 113 144],  [212 137 157],  [213 133 158]
```

I've tried several ways to convert this to 3d-NUmpy array without success. In the snippet code, for example, I continue to got an array of string.

```py
train = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_dir, 'trainset.csv'))
train['image'] = train['image'].map(lambda x: x.replace('\n',','))
train['image'] = train['image'].map(lambda x: np.asarray(x))
```

Does someone know a simple way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the asarray method will infer the data type from the data itself. Because you're reading in from a csv file, they are all strings.

You can use the dtype parameter of the np.asarray method to set the data type.

```
import numpy as np
data = [['3','4'],['45','75']]
num_array = np.asarray(data, dtype=np.int)
print(num_array.dtype)
```

So your code would just need to change to:

```
train = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(data_dir, 'trainset.csv'))
train['image'] = train['image'].map(lambda x: x.replace('\n',','))
train['image'] = train['image'].map(lambda x: np.asarray(x, dtype=np.int))
```

Where you can change the dtype=int to np.whatever datatype you want.